# Unmanaged DLL cannot be consumed by ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: .net, iis, unmanaged, windows-server

I have developed a Win32 C++ unmanaged DLL that I have built in release mode. I am attempting to consume the DLL from within a .net MVC app running on IIS 8.5 and Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacentre which is an Azure Virtual Machine.

Everything runs fine on my development machine. However, when I deploy to the server and try to access the MVC site I get an error message saying that the unmanaged DLL was not found. To rectify this apparently the unmanaged DLL should be registered as an IIS module. So I register the Module in IIS manager however now when I try to access the MVC website I get a `503 Service Unavailable` response and when I check back in IIS manager I can see that the application pool has stopped.

It seems that just registering the native module with IIS causes the application pool to crash when the MVC app gets it's first request. I have also set the app pool to `Enable 32bit Applications = true` as the DLL is 32bit.

I have notice that in the IIS Event Logs there is an Event `5002 Error - Application pool 'DefaultAppPool' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool`.

Also at the point the app pool stops I don't think any code trying to load or access the unmanaged DLL has executed. It seems to be simply that the registration of the unmanaged DLL is preventing the MVC app from starting. I have tried just registering an unmanaged DLL has the minimum amount of code (just one method returning `bool`) and I didn't even reference this DLL module from my MVC app but still if I register this basic DLL with IIS it prevents the MVC app from starting and the app pool is stopped.

What could be the cause and how could I resolve this? Could this be something to do with running Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacentre being an Azure Virtual Machine?

update: Process Monitor screen captures.

[Full size image 1](http://s240.photobucket.com/user/BrownWarrior/media/2014_04_25_screencapture_dllnotfound_01.jpg.html)

[Full size image 2](http://s240.photobucket.com/user/BrownWarrior/media/2014_04_25_screencapture_dllnotfound_02.jpg.html)

Comment: "To rectify this apparently the unmanaged DLL should be registered as an IIS module" is a completely wrong approach. Drop the native library to %windir%\system32 and see if it can be found. IIS native modules have a strict convention which of course your library is not qualified. Please remove this library from module list, and then post exactly what is the error message on ASP.NET side.

Comment: Hey Lex, thanks for the reply, I have tried adding the DLL to system32. The DLL is also in the MVC app bin folder and the app root folder. The error produced is `Unable to load DLL 'customdll.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)` The MVC app is targeting x86, the DLL is Win32 and both are release builds.

Comment: If the native dll was compiled as 32 bit, then you have to deploy it to WOW64 paths, such as `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` instead of `C:\Windows\system32`. ASP.NET never loads native dependencies from bin folder or root folder, so leaving that dll in those locations is useless.

Comment: I have already tried both of these folders without success. When I run the app on my development machine I'm pretty sure the DLL is located in, and accessed from the bin folder. Also most of the documentation / questions about PInvoke suggest that the first place the DLL is looked for is in the bin folder. Although I don't know if it is different specifically for asp.net

Comment: Also if I publish to a free Azure `mysite.azurewesites.net` then the DLL is found in the bin directory. It's only when I publish to the Azure virtual machine that the DLL cannot be found. I'm wondering if maybe there is a Windows Server or IIS configuration that needs to be set to allow the DLL to be discovered?

Comment: Azure Web Site is a completely different monster. Try to utilize Process Monitor, as it tells where the dll is being searched.

Comment: I have captured in Process Monitor the activity of one attempt to load the DLL. It seems there is some success in locating it but it is also showing a few issues but I'm not quite sure what action to take. I have added links to full size screen captures above. Please could you have a look?

Comment: Can only guess your PInvoke code was not right. As that needs more info to debug, you'd better open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: I don't think that there is anything wrong with the PInvoke code as it works fine both on my development machine and on the free azure website. Thank you very much for the help you have given! I have asked a new question expressing the problem differently - http://stackoverflow.com/q/23353342/745491 So I shall probably delete this one in a week or so

Comment: @FunkyFresh84 how did you get past the apppool being disabled.Please share this as I could not find any other solution addressing it.

Comment: @Gotalove It's been a little while since I experienced this problem, however I think I do recall. My error I believe was trying to register the native dll as an IIS Module. IIS Modules execute during the IIS Request Pipeline. My code was not an IIS module and not intended to be. Only modules which inherit the Pipeline interfaces will be accepted. Anything else crashes the App Pool. So registration as an IIS module should never have been attempted. There was an alternative solution to the initial problem of the dll not being found. See the link in the comment above to my other question.